# Changing Elements in a list of Strings

Tags: python

I want to create a list of strings. The Strings should all be the same except for some elements, where they should be different. Doing this I came across a strange behaviour:

```
x = ['spam', 'spam', 'spam', 'spam', 'spam']
x[1] = 'buzz'
x[2] = 'buzz'
x

Out[35]: ['spam', 'buzz', 'buzz', 'spam', 'spam']
```

But on the other hand:

```
y = ['spam'] * 5
y[1:3] = ['buzz']
y
Out[36]: ['spam', 'buzz', 'spam', 'spam']
```

Can someone pleas tell me what I am doing wrong? Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: in place `y[1:3] = ['buzz']` make `y[1:3] = ['buzz'] * 2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The assignment:

```
y = ['spam'] * 5
```

Will cause `y` to be a list like this:

```
['spam', 'spam', 'spam', 'spam', 'spam']
```

The *array slice* `y[1:3]` captures the elements at index 1 and 2, and looks like this:

```
['spam', 'spam']
```

Aligning the slice to the array at index 1 (where the slice starts):

```
['spam', 'spam', 'spam', 'spam', 'spam']  # y
        ['spam', 'spam']                  # y[1:3]
```

Now, when you make the assignment `y[1:3] = ['buzz']`, it essentially turns this into the below:

```
['spam', 'buzz', 'spam', 'spam']
        ['buzz']
```

Answer (score 1):

`y[1:3]` is a slice of the list and you replace this slice with a list composed of a single element.

```
spam spam spam spam spam
     \       /
      \     /
       \   /
spam    buzz   spam spam
```

IIUC, what you want to do is replace it with a list of the same size composed of N times the new element (buzz).

You could write

```
y[1:3] = ['buzz', 'buzz']
# or equivalently
y[1:3] = ['buzz'] * 2
```

which is equivalent and more efficient than using a loop like this:

```
for i in [1, 2]:
    y[i] = 'buzz'
# or equivalently
for i in range(1, 3):
    y[i] = 'buzz'
```

As a sidenote, here's another pitfall. A string is an iterator, so whenever an iterator is expected and you pass a string, the string is iterated over character per character, as a list of one-character strings:

```
y[1:3] = 'buzz'
print(y)
# ['spam', 'b', 'u', 'z', 'z', 'spam', 'spam', 'spam']
```

In this case, slice `[1:3]` is replaced with the iterator you provided, which is 'buzz', treated as `['b', 'u', 'z', 'z']`.

Comment: Wow, You guys are really fast! Thanks for all the answers!

Answer (score 0):

```
y[1:3] = ['buzz']
```

This is not the same as `y[1] = 'buzz'` plus `y[2] = 'buzz'`

Just do a for loop

```
for i in [1,2..whatever you need to change]:
    y[i] = 'buzz'
```